# Why the images of my filterizr gallery appears one above the other?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im doing my resume page and i have some problems with filterizr plugin

I have use it in my page but it does not working the same way like the examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC18D.jpg
As you can see in the image my gallery images appears one above the other, the problem is temporarily resolved only if you refresh the page several times, but it will appear again.

I asked to the plugin creator about the problem but he does not answer me

This is my page if you want to try it out, there you can view the real problem, i hope that you can help me solving this: danielcruz.esy.es

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: i made an example, I hope will be useful: http://plnkr.co/edit/pQfDbhVTr0pwint5NfR7?p=preview

Comment: the original plugin is right here: http://yiotis.net/filterizr/

Answer (score 4):

I am the creator of Filterizr. Excuse me for the late answer to your issue.

Actually the answer to your problem can be found on Filterizr's own website.

At [yiotis.net/filterizr](http://yiotis.net/filterizr) -> FAQ & Caveats -> Q.4 Under Caveats "My images appear without height"

And here is the answer as provided on the website:

> If the height of your .filtr-item elements depends on images then you might have trouble, because their loading might be slow the height of your items might be messed up. To solve this issue you can either set the height of your images explicitly or perhaps make use of DeSandro's imagesLoaded script which is only 5kb!

The problem is caused because Filterizr is hit off on document ready event but the images are not finished loading. Either set a fixed height or make use of the aforementioned plugin.

Comment: How would you use imagesLoaded? I can't find a method in Filterizr to 'reLayout' when an image has loaded. I would apply Filterizr after all images have loaded (which I assume is you solution), except I'm implementing lazysizes - so images are garenteed to load at different times. Cheers